# Caused By: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic-10.x

I had changed jdk from 1.6 to 1.7 and started getting mention error.
my application running in Weblogic.

**i had changed below file/location**

1.setEnv.cmd
2.build.property
3.build configuration
4. project facet , build path , target runtime , eclipse.ini 
almost all the place which relatd to jdk i made changes but still getting error.

**Below is coming after starting server**
Starting WLS with line:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_9\bin\java    -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m

Comment: Why not update to Java 11 or 12?

Comment: `Xms`/`Xmx` do not affect the permGenSpace, you need to use `-XX:MaxPermSize` if the solution is to increase the available memory for this zone